# Getting Process Information from Process Handle

Tags: c++, windows

I need to get the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` of an external process for use in my application, I have the process handle and process ID, but I don't know how to go about getting the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` out of that.

I'm using C++(11), Visual Studio 2012, running on Windows. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want it if you already have the process _handle_ and _id_?

Comment: What information do you actually need? You already have, according to you, 50% of the information the function returns. The only thing you're missing is the ID and handle of the initial thread. Why do you need that?

Comment: I need it to check if the process that started the application is still alive, the application that started the application (lets call it application1) passes on its process ID when it starts the application (lets call that application2) and then application2 derives the handle from the Process ID. - But I don't know how to go about getting the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` from there.

Comment: How were you planning on using the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` to determine whether the application is still alive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PROCESS_INFORMATION` is filled by `CreateProcess()`.  That ship has sailed; the process was already started.

Let's focus on what you *really* want to do.  To find out if a process has terminated, first use `OpenProcess()` to obtain a handle to the process.  You'll need the PID, which you already have.  Then `WaitForSingleObject()` will tell you if it is terminated.  Pass `INFINITE` for the 2nd argument to block until the process terminates.  Pass `0` if you want to poll.  Finally, use `CloseHandle()` to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

`PROCESS_INFORMMATION` provides 4 pieces of information:

```
HANDLE hProcess
HANDLE hThread
DWORD dwProcessID
DWORD dwThreadID
```

You say you already have two of those values - the Process Handle and Process ID.  So that just leaves the Thread Handle and Thread ID.  Those belong to the first thread created for the process.  You can use `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`, `Thread32First()`, and `Thread32Next()` to enumerate the running threads looking for Thread IDs that belong to a given Process ID, and then use `OpenThread()` to get the Thread Handle of a given Thread ID.  The tricky part is identifying which Thread ID is the first thread.  That information is not readily available outside of `CreateProcess()`.

Answer (score 0):

The information you need can be obtained with the [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) since it returns both the process ID and the parent process ID.  An example of its use can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).