# How to get PROCESS_INFORMATION from OpenProcess()?

Tags: windows, winapi

In Windows, I can get PROCESS_INFORMATION via CreateProcess(). However, is it possible to get PROCESS_INFORMATION via OpenProcess()?

Comment: What information do you want to retrieve?

Comment: If you can get the information you need from `CreateProcess`, why don't you just remember that information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Process Information from Process Handle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164685/getting-process-information-from-process-handle)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Because I am not creating a process. I'm only opening existing processes.

Comment: @manuell: I'm trying to retrieve the hThread HANDLE.

Comment: Which thread are you interested in? There could be more than one.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Good question. I suppose I can get the thread handle by enumerating the threads and opening the needed threads using their pids.

Comment: When you enumerate them, and find a bunch of threads, how will you pick one? And what will you do with it anyway. This is one of those questions where you did not give us any context at all. It feels like an XY question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm making a debugger.

Comment: @drum Take a look here: http://devonstrawntech.tumblr.com/post/15878429193/how-to-write-a-windows-debugger-references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comments, you are actually interested in enumerating the threads within a process. You can do that using the tool help library. Call `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` to create a snapshot of the process. Then enumerate the threads with `Thread32First` and `Thread32Next`. MSDN has sample code here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686852.aspx

This will enumerate the threads in the snapshot, referring to each thread by its ID. You then obtain a handle to a thread, should you need it, by calling `OpenThread`.